# Loss functions in tensorflow (with an if - else)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying a different loss functions in tensorflow.

The loss function I want is  a kind of an epsilon insensitive function (this is componentwise):

```
if(|yData-yModel|<epsilon):
    loss=0
else
    loss=|yData-yModel|
```

I tried this solution:

```
yData=tf.placeholder("float",[None,numberOutputs]) 

yModel=model(...

epsilon=0.2
epsilonTensor=epsilon*tf.ones_like(yData)
loss=tf.maximum(tf.abs(yData-yModel)-epsilonTensor,tf.zeros_like(yData))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.25)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

I also used

```
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.001,0.9)
```

I do not find any error in the implementation. However, it does not converge, while the loss = tf.square(yData-yModel) converges and loss=tf.maximum(tf.square(yData-yModel)-epsilonTensor,tf.zeros_like(yData)) also converges.

So, I also tried something simpler loss=tf.abs(yData-yModel) and it also does not converge. Am I making some mistake, or having problems with the non-differentiability of the abs at zero or something else? What is happenning with the abs function?

Comment: I think it is (like tf.square(yData-yModel)). However, tensorflow must be dealing with that, since the backpropagation algorithm minimizes the sum of the output erros!?

Comment: what do you mean but "not converge"? loss is not stabilizing? or you simply do not get model that you would like to get?

Comment: When I use loss as the square() form, the variable precision=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(loss,tf.float32)) goes to something very close to zero. When I use the abs() form, it just oscilates close to the initial value!

Comment: I think your function is non-convex and thus hard for gradient descent to optimize

Comment: Definitely convex.

Comment: Your loss function looks a little strange, since there is a step of size epsilon in it when the difference exceeds epsilon. Shouldn't that be |yData-yModel|-epsilon in the else branch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When your loss is something like `Loss(x)=abs(x-y)`, then solution is an unstable fixed point of SGD -- start your minimization with a point arbitrarily close to the solution, and the next step will increase the loss.

Having a stable fixed point is a requirement for convergence of an iterative procedure like SGD. In practice this means your optimization will move towards a local minimum, but after getting close enough, will jump around the solution with steps proportional to the learning rate. Here's a toy TensorFlow program that illustrates the problem

```
x = tf.Variable(0.)
loss_op = tf.abs(x-1.05)
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss_op)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
xvals = []
for i in range(20):
  unused, loss, xval = sess.run([train_op, loss_op, x])
  xvals.append(xval)
pyplot.plot(xvals)
```

[image: Graph of x estimate]

Some solutions to the problem:

1. Use a more robust solver such as the Proximal Gradient Method
2. Use more SGD friendly loss function such as Huber Loss
3. Use learning rate schedule to gradually decrease learning rate

Here's a way to implement (3) on the toy problem above

```
x = tf.Variable(0.)
loss_op = tf.abs(x-1.05)

step = tf.Variable(0)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
      0.2,   # Base learning rate.
      step,  # Current index into the dataset.
      1,     # Decay step.
      0.9    # Decay rate
)

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss_op, global_step=step)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
xvals = []
for i in range(40):
  unused, loss, xval = sess.run([train_op, loss_op, x])
  xvals.append(xval)
pyplot.plot(xvals)
```

[image]

Comment: Does that vanish when one removes the weird step in the loss function when epsilon is exceeded by putting  |yData-yModel|-epsilon in the else branch? Maybe that's just an artifact of that strangeness.